# DEC2BIN not found in Microsoft® Excel® (Microsoft 365 MSO)?

Tags: microsoft-excel

For some reason, my Excel does not recognize the [DEC2BIN](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dec2bin-function-0f63dd0e-5d1a-42d8-b511-5bf5c6d43838) function.

It does not seem to be restricted to a particular versinon of Excel though ..

> DEC2BIN function Excel for Microsoft 365 Excel for Microsoft 365 for
> Mac Excel for the web Excel 2021 for Mac Excel 2019 Excel 2019 for Mac
> Excel 2016 Excel 2016 for Mac Excel 2013 Excel 2010 Excel 2007 Excel
> for Mac 2011 Excel Starter 2010 Less

My version is

> Microsoft® Excel® pour Microsoft 365 MSO (Version 2302 Build 16.0.16130.20298) 32 bits

When I type `=DEC2BIN` in a cell, it simply returns `#NAME?`

VBA doesn't like it either

```
Public Function DecToBin(DecNum As Variant) As String
    Dim d As Decimal
    d = Application.WorksheetFunction.Dec2Bin("FFF")
End Function
```

This just throws "Property not found on class WorksheetFunction"

Is it some sort of add-in that's not documented anywhere ?

Comment: in vba you are using Bin2Dec and `FFF` is not a binary string.  It is probably hex.  And please show the full formula you used.  What was the input to your DEC2BIN

Comment: Heh, fair enough, it seems to work in VBA after all .. But not in an Excel cell.

Comment: What is the full formula you are using in Excel.  `=DEC2BIN("FFF") will error.

Comment: I'm trying with `=DEC2BIN(18)`

Comment: interesting, I am at a loss why you would get that.

Comment: If you have that function in VBA then it is possible that you are overriding the built-in function as the names are identical and getting some oddness as a result. Have you tried this in a clean workbook without any VBA and made sure that your personal workbook is similarly devoid of functions named identically to built in functions?

Comment: Otherwise name your function as something like `DecToBinTest` so that Excel doesn't think you are trying to replace `DEC2BIN` with your own [user defined function](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-custom-functions-in-excel-2f06c10b-3622-40d6-a1b2-b6748ae8231f). You may have to close and reopen Excel after deleting or renaming the function to get it to work properly.

Comment: Unfortunately I tried from a blank workbook, simply inserting `=DEC2BIN(10)` simply won't work, and I'm clueless at this point.

Comment: Try in "Programs and Features" to find Office, right-click it and select "Change", to repair Office.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of likely problems.

> When I type =DEC2BIN in a cell, it simply returns #NAME?

Just `=DEC2BIN` in a cell returns `#NAME`? for me as well. Because you're not calling the function with expected parameters it may well believe you are calling up a named cell that does not exist called `DEC2BIN` instead of the actual function `DEC2BIN()`.

`=DEC2BIN(18)` returns `10010` for me.

As a test you can select a cell and then go to the Formulas tab in the ribbon and select "Define name" and give the cell a name such as "NamedTest"

From then on you can access that value as `=NamedTest` which is the format you've just tested.

If you are trying to use a function then you must remember the brackets: `=DEC2BIN(18)`

Additionally you should not be creating VBA functions with the same name as built in functions.

If you have a function in VBA with the same name then it is possible that you are overriding the built-in function.

---

It seems this might be a localisation issue judging by your comment. Some of the excel functions change depending on your language and may need you to find out the correct function name.

From [ExcelFunctions](https://www.excelfunctions.eu/DEC2BIN/English-French) the suggested function name in French is simply `=DECBIN()`

I do not know if there is a complete list of localised function names in Excel from Microsoft, but sites like [Excel Translator](https://en.excel-translator.de/dec2bin/) or Excel Functions that I used above may be helpful.

---

An alternative to `=DECBIN()` which supports numbers larger than 512 is the `=BASE(number, radix)` function with a radix value of "2".

`=BASE(28474738,2)` which will give a string with a base2 (binary) representation of any given length.

BASE should be the same in French as it is in English.

Function found as a suggestion [at StackOverflow.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58714251/278545)

Comment: I omitted the brackets by accident in the question, but I do invoke it with arguments (10 in my case) using `=DEC2BIN(10)`. This simply returns `#NAME?`, even on a new, blank workbook. Actually, it returns `#NOM?` in my case, because it's in French. I'm starting to think the French version of Excel took some obscure name that I can't figure out. And the documentation won't help me with this.

Comment: @ArthurAttout in that case you probably just want [`DECBIN()`](https://www.excelfunctions.eu/DEC2BIN/English-French)

Comment: Ok indeed, this is the alias in french .. In all my turmoil I got confused and believed that `DECBIN` was built-in, supporting maximum 512, and `DEC2BIN`, a superior implementation that allowed larger numbers. I wanted to use this. But re-reading the original documentation about DEC2BIN, I should have noticed it doesn't support numbers larger than 512 either. Thanks for the link to the translator though, it will definetly come handy next time !

Comment: @ArthurAttout it seems that Stack Overflow has some intriguing solutions to make it able to use numbers larger than 512: https://www.google.com/search?q=dec2bin+larger+than+512+site:stackoverflow.com Personally I quite like the somewhat elegant suggestion to just use the `=BASE(number, radix)` function with a radix value of "2" such as `=BASE(28474738,2)` which will give a string with a base2 (binary) representation.

Comment: @ArthurAttout answer updated

Comment: Ok, now that I notice `BASE` exists, I'm just wondering why  `DEC2BIN` has been introduced at all .. Maybe `BASE` appeared after. If not, I have no idea why both exist.

Answer (score 1):

A helpful looking website, https://www.perfectxl.com/excel-glossary/what-is-excel-function/translations-english-french/ , shows the French version's function name to be `DECBIN`.

Could be worth trying. And if they are correct, saving the website for future difficulties could be an idea!

*Sorry, now I see a comment in which that name is mentioned. Still, the site could be of use.*